# The sum of specific component in a list of objects

Tags: java, list, oop, hashset

I have made a project using a Hashset of objects. Each object has a game name and game cost. An admin should input these values and then a costumer will choice which game he will rent and I need to show at the end how much all the games costs.

So how I can sum the same variable (rentFees) multilabel times?

here is a simulator to how it looks like while the real project is crazy complicated.

---

```
public Games( String gameTitle, double rentFees)

gameTitle= input.nextLine();

rentFees= input.nextDouble();
```

---

Thanks,

Comment: Showing a [mcve] will be helpful.

Comment: *"So how I can [do something] multiple times?"* With a **loop** over the list/set of objects.